# show all my unanswered questions from SE

Tags: feature-request, search, unanswered-questions

Any way how to get

- my **all un-answered** questions
- from across **all SE sites**?

Comment: I think the only way to do this at present is to rig something up using [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Robert: why did you close the question that was asked first?